# Need to have user input stored into an arrayList and saved to a txt file to be able to pull up back once requested

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, menu, user-input

I am attempting to have my user read from my menu and make a selection either option 1 (add a product name, store name, purchase date and cost), option 2 display the arrayList with the purchase objects the were inputted and option 3 exit the program and thank the user for using my program all while have exceptions to ensure that the user doesn't input and valid entries. Now I need to be able to store to a txt file and have the ability to pull it back up for review or modification.

I built my menu and and I believe that I have setup my arrayList correctly for proper user input, I have methods for each string that the user will be inputting and exceptions to ensure that the inputs are valid

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Create menu options 
    TheMenu();
}

public static void TheMenu() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String purchase[] = new String[4];


    int option;
    do { // loop until Exit (option 3) is selected
        System.out.println("\nMenu Options");
        System.out.println("\n1 Add a purchase");
        System.out.println("\n2 Display a purchase");
        System.out.println("\n3 Exit");

        option = input.nextInt();

        if (option == 1) {
            displayPurchaseObjects(purchase);
        }

        if (option == 2) {
            System.out.println();
        }

        while (option == 3) 
            System.out.println("Thank you for using purchase programmer!");
        System.exit(3); 


    //Create a list to store Purchase objects
    ArrayList<String> displayPurchaseObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    while(input.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Enter the product name "); 
        String productName = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter the store name"); 
        String storeName = input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the purchase date (i.e. 06/30/2019) ");
        int purchaseDate = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the cost ");
        double cost = input.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

}

```
    public void  productName(String productName) { 
        try {
            for(int i = 1; i < productName.length(); i++) { 
        }       
    }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a product name ");         
        }
    }

    public void storeName(String storeName) {
        try {
            for(int i = 1; i < storeName.length(); i++) { 
        }       
    }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a store name");
        }
    }

    public void purchaseDate(String date) {
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(date);
        try {
            format.parse(date);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid date");
        }
    }

    public void cost(double newCost) 
         throws InputMismatchException{
        double cost;
        if(newCost >= 1)
            cost = newCost;
        else 
            throw new InputMismatchException("Cost must be a integer and more the $0 ");
    }
```

I am receiving a compilation error because of a "}" which I cannot find the cause and the program should be allowing me to make a selection (1,2 or 3) and the should be able to add my purchase objects to my "displayPurchaseObjects" arrayList

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question clearly, the problem at hand is the compilation error - not able to find a "}".

In your code, you are missing out the "}" after this -

```
do { // loop until Exit (option 3) is selected
    System.out.println("\nMenu Options");
    System.out.println("\n1 Add a purchase");
    System.out.println("\n2 Display a purchase");
    System.out.println("\n3 Exit");

    option = input.nextInt();

    if (option == 1) {
        displayPurchaseObjects(purchase);
    }

    if (option == 2) {
        System.out.println();
    }

} while (option == 3);

System.out.println("Thank you for using purchase programmer!");
// Non zero exit code is only for abnormal termination. Use 0.
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: It's not that he is missing "}" but He has to move the "}" from a few lines down to where you're pointing.  https://imgur.com/a/C6joQUb     Then there is the issue of "displayPurchaseObjects(purchase);"  this is not a function. it is an ArrayList he defines after he tries to use it. So It will give another compilation error.

Comment: Thank you for the input I was able to go back and trace my steps with the feedback provided and correct my errors. Once again thank you very much!!

Comment: @BryanAMorris IFF this solved your problem, please mark it as solved.